# .htacess rewrite url for different dynamic pages like category.php or subcategory.php or product.php

Tags: php, .htaccess

hi i want to know how to rewrite url for differ pages

for example:

http://example.com/category.php?cat=$category

in .htacces url i want like this
example.com/category/

example.com/subCategory.php?cat=$category&subCat=$subCategory
in .htacces url i want like this
example.com/category/subcategory/

example.com/product.php?product=$product
in .htacces url i want like this
example.com/product/

thanx in advance

Comment: example.com/category.php?category=agricultre
i want in like 

hhtp://example.com/agriculture

when i click on this link 
example.com/agriculture

i get the  value through $_GET['category'] on category.php pls help me im confused regarding htacess

Answer (score 0):

Using the rewrite engine and rewrite rules you can achieve this pretty easily.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/category/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/?$ /category.php?cat=$1
```

Now just apply the same logic to your other scenarios.

Comment: example.com/category.php?category=agricultre
i want in like 

hhtp://example.com/agriculture

when i click on this link 
example.com/agriculture

i get the  value through $_GET['category'] on category.php pls help me im confused regarding htacess